# Why can't I output the value of my promise in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, promise

I have a property that returns a resolves promise with a string like `return Promise.resolve('foo');` Then in handlebars:

```
{{log model.skin_css}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href={{model.skin_css}}>
```

Logs:

```
Promise {__ember_meta__: Meta, [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: "foo"}
```

And outputs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[object Promise]">
```

How can  I get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property value *is* a Promise, and that is exactly what is being rendered. What you are expecting is more "magical" behavior provided by, e.g., [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data), which returns a [PromiseObject](https://github.com/emberjs/data) instead of just a Promise.